# How can I make this Python code shorter?

Tags: python

I want there to be a 7/10 chance of somebody successfully completing an action, such as climbing a wall. I couldn't get a set of integers to work with random.randint, so I had to retype it 10 times, like this:

```
import random

print('You try to climb the wall.')

climbResult = random.randint(1,10)


elif climbResult == (1):
    print('You were successful.')

elif climbResult == (2):
    print('You were successful.')

elif climbResult == (3):
    print('You were successful.')

elif climbResult == (4):
    print('You were successful.')

elif climbResult == (5):
    print('You were successful.')

elif climbResult == (6):
    print('You were successful.')

elif climbResult == (7):
    print('You were successful.')

elif climbResult == (8):
    print('You were unsuccessful.')

elif climbResult == (9):
    print('You were unsuccessful.')

elif climbResult == (10):
    print('You were unsuccessful.')
```

It was a pain to add in the numbers over and over, and this was only with 10 parts. I would just like to make there be two if statements, one with a 70% chance to print that you were successful, and the other with a 30% chance to print that you were unsuccessful.

I'm sorry that this is a really simple question, and the way I asked it was probably hard to understand. I've only been learning Python for two weeks and I had trouble asking it in English, as it isn't my first language.

Answer (score 12):

```
if climbResult <= 7:
     print('You were successful.')
else:
     print('You were unsuccessful.')
```

Comment: That's a lot of upvotes in a minute.  Nicely done!

Comment: That was perfect, and really fast, thank you so much!

Comment: I guess that's the way it goes - dig up a complicated answer on an underdocumented third party Django package, nothing.  Basic arithmetic comparisons, here come the upvotes.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: yeah, that's totally the way it goes.  I think part of it is that people are reluctant to upvote answers they're not sure of themselves.  (Some of my personal favourite answers didn't even get an upvote from the OP..)

Comment: @DSM -- It's also a matter of traffic.  When I see a questions which is clearly about basic python principles/modules, I think "Ooo, I can probably answer that one \*click click\*" vs. a question where I see the Django tag and I explicitly avoid clicking on it since I know I won't be able to answer that one.

Comment: To me, the real irony is getting this many upvotes for a question that many downvotes. My take-away is that neither are very meaningful...

Answer (score 6):

For a slightly fun and different way of looking at the problem:

```
random.choice(['You were successful']*7 + ['You were unsuccessful']*3)
```

It's also a 1-liner if you don't count the import ... That's gotta count for something ...

Comment: I think that answer follows the 30-70 spec to the letter.

Answer (score 3):

Since you say you just care about this saying "successful" in 70% of the cases
and "unsuccessful" for everything else you could as well use a random number.

```
# import random

def answer():
  if random.uniform(0, 10) < 7:
    return 'successful'
  else:
    return 'unsuccessful'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if climbResult <= 7: 
    print("Success")
else: 
    print ("Fail")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return climbResult in range(1,8)
```